# Google photos link sharing: private or public

Tags: privacy, google-photos

I just posted this on the Google product support forum, but I might receive more feedback here.

What I wonder is whether Google photos would detect and stop brute force album share link discovery attempts. What I mean is, could someone put up a server that simply tries out randomly generated Google photos album links to see if it's an actual link.

I think it's quite straightforward for Google to detect and block this, thus making the link almost private and only available to those it has been shared with. The chances of generating a single random link that just happens to be an actual album seem very small to me.

However, if Google doesn't attempt to detect and block such link searching then shared albums can be assumed to be simply public. This would be a privacy leak in my opinion and I'm sure plenty of content will have leaked already. It's just waiting for the bomb to drop.

Does anyone have insights in this matter?